# What happens to malloc'ed memory after exec() changes the program image?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, exec

I know that when I call one of the `exec()` system calls in Linux that it will replace the currently running process with a new image. So when I fork a new process and run `exec()`, the child will be replaced with the new process.

What happens to any memory I've allocated from the heap? Say I want to parse an arbitrary number of commands and send it into `exec()`. To hold this arbitrary number, I'll likely have to allocate memory at some point since I don't think I can do it correctly with static sized arrays, so I'll likely use `malloc()` or something equivalent.

I need to keep this memory allocated until after I've called `exec()`, but `exec()` never returns.

Does the memory get reclaimed by the operating system?

Comment: Btw here're a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617332/what-happens-with-memory-usage-after-exec

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When you call `fork()`, a copy of the calling process is created. This child process is (almost) exactly the same as the parent, i.e. memory allocated by `malloc()` is preserved and you're free to read or modify it. The modifications will not be visible to the parent process, though, as the parent and child processes are completely separate.

When you call `exec()` in the child, the child process is replaced by a new process. From execve(2):

```
execve() does not return on success, and the text, data, bss, and stack
of the calling process are overwritten by that of the program loaded.
```

By overwriting the `data` segment, the `exec()` call effectively reclaims the memory that was allocated before by `malloc()`.

The parent process is unaffected by all this. Assuming that you allocated the memory in the parent process before calling `fork()`, the memory is still available in the parent process.

EDIT: Modern implementations of `malloc()` use anonymous memory mappings, see mmap(2). According to execve(2), memory mappings are not preserved over an `exec()` call, so this memory is also reclaimed.

Comment: That's doesn't explain what happens to the heap. Okay, the data segment is overwritten, but that implies the heap gets corrupted, not reset.

Comment: Heap is the data segment. In a simple implementation, `malloc()` would use `brk()` to grow the data segment and get more memory. When the data segment is overwritten, its size is also reset and the memory is effectively freed.

Comment: I think "heap corruption" normally means that the data structures in the heap that `malloc()` uses get corrupted (e.g. when a pointer is freed twice). When the data segment is overwritten, there's nothing to get corrupted anymore.

Comment: How does the heap know it has no memory to serve the user request from and has to call `brk()`? It uses service data for that. That service data resides in the data segment. Doing anything with that data will lead to classic heap corruption.

Comment: Upon `exec()`, the "service data" (the initial values of internal variable used by `malloc()`) is overwritten to reflect the situation at program start, i.e. zero bytes allocated with `malloc()`. When `malloc()` is first called, it knows that it needs to call `brk()`.

Comment: But memory got from OS when earlier (pre-`exec()`) calls to `brk()` will be then not used *and* still allocated to the process and that's a memory leak.

Comment: No. The memory will be freed because the data segment is overwritten and its size is reset to the size of the data segment of the new process. There's no memory for the process outside the data segment. After the program has started, `malloc()` uses `brk()` to grow the data segment (by incresing the address of the program break).

Comment: Actually, in modern implementations `malloc()` uses anonymous memory mappings acquired with `mmap()`. According to execve(2), memory mappings are not preserved over `exec()`, so no memory leak is possible this way either.

Answer (score 5):

The entire heap -- allocated memory, and all of the logic malloc
uses to manage it -- is part of the process image which gets
replaced.  It simply disappears, as far as your process is
concerned.  The system, of course, recovers it and recycles it.

Comment: what happened to memory on stack?