# Heap memory management of child process upon forkpty() and execl()?

Tags: c++, linux, fork

I have a C++ app I'm developing in Linux.  I'm allocating some dynamic memory and ultimately calling forkpty().  The child process is calling execl() and as we know, execl() never returns if it succeeds to execute the command.  Furthermore, as we know, forkpty() makes a copy of all the parent's data.  So, if the child() process never returns control back to my application in order to ultimately do memory cleanup, is it safe to say one better not have any dynamic memory allocated at the time execl() is called from the child process???  I can't believe I could not find this one on here...  Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to malloc'ed memory after exec() changes the program image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429141/what-happens-to-malloced-memory-after-exec-changes-the-program-image)

Answer (score 1):

Allocated memory is part of the process image; when you call
`execl`, the entire process image is replaced, and any memory in
it simply "disappears" like the rest of it, returning to the OS,
which will then use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

All of the "forked" process memory is freed as part of `execl()` (if the call is successful).

If this wasn't the case, there would be a lot of memory leaks all over a regular linux system, as it's almost impossible to write anything even a little complex without allocating memory, and, for example, if the arguments to `execl()` are allocated, you couldn't possibly free them before calling `execl()`.